# запись сообщения в БД discord.py

Tags: python

Пытаюсь сделать команду #GetChannelID. То есть, пользователь пишет #getChannelID "id".
и этот текст должен добавиться в базу данных. Ошибок не выдает, но и не работает. Буду благодарен любой помощи

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def getChannelID(ctx, *, text):
    dbo = sqlite3.connect("Discord.db")
    db = dbo.cursor()
    name = guild.id
    nameG = Guild.name
    db.execute(f"insert into '{name}' values ('{nameG}', '{guild.member_count}', {text}, null)'")
    dbo.commit()

    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f"Данные сервера **'{name}'** успешно добавлены!", color = 0x0c0c0c ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны передать значение  в нужный столбец, у каждого значению должны быть данные:

```
url_database = "Discord.db"

with sqlite3.connect(mainUrlBase) as connection:
   cur = connection.cursor()
   cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO `имя таблицы`(`Значение 1`,
               `Значение 2`,
               `Значение 3`,
               `Значение 4`)
               VALUES (
               'Данные 1',
               'Данные 2',
               'Данные 3',
               'Данные 4',)""")
    connection.commit()
```

Comment: Вопрос решил, большое спасибо